# Where does Joomla put file when using type="file" on module field?

Tags: joomla, upload, module, field

I've created a module that has:

```
<field
                    name="arquivo"
                    type="file"
                    label="Arquivo de Aniversariantes"
                    description="Arquivo na extensão .CSV com as colunas: NOME, DIA, MES"
                    size="200" 
                    required="required"
                    accept="text/comma-separated-values, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.msexcel, text/anytext"
                />
```

When i try to read that parameter by $params->get("arquivo") the only thing i get is the filename. I've already did a search on Directories for the filename and found nothing. Does joomla really upload that file? If it does, where it puts? 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I've just looked into *form* tag on Joomla's Administrative Panel on the selected module, it's missing the enctype for files, maybe this is the problem? If it is, how can i put it there?

Answer (score 1):

After you add the multipart encoding to the form in your xml definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
```

you will find an array "files" which looks like: (here "pdf" is the field name)

```
 'name' => array ( 'pdf' => '', ), 
 'type' => array ( 'pdf' => '', ), 
 'tmp_name' => array ( 'pdf' => '', ), 
 'error' => array ( 'pdf' => 4, ), 
 'size' => array ( 'pdf' => 0, ), )
```

when empty, and

```
 'name' => array ( 'pdf' => '8.jpg', ), 
 'type' => array ( 'pdf' => 'image/jpeg', ), 
 'tmp_name' => array ( 'pdf' => '/tmp/phpk1fDmB', ), 
 'error' => array ( 'pdf' => 0, ), 
 'size' => array ( 'pdf' => 26975, ),
```

when full. The temporary folder is the php tmp folder, not Joomla's.  You may adapt this function for your needs:

```
private function getFile($key,$destinationFolder) {
    /**
     *  now let's process uploads: the array files contains a key "$key" which is the key name.
     *  we need to copy the files uploaded
     *  (if any are there and if they match the field filter = pdf)
     *  and set the data->pdf to its new path.
     * */
             $file = JRequest::getVar('jform', array(), 'files', 'array');
             if ($file['error'][$key]!="0") {
                error_log('no files uploaded, exiting now');
                return "";
             }

             //error_log('OFFER FOUND FILES '.var_export($file,true));
             $tempName = $file['tmp_name'][$key];
             $tempFullPath = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir').$tempName;
             $type = $file['type'][$key];
             $name = $file['name'][$key];
             //error_log('DATA FOUND: '. "temp: $tempName , type: $type, name: $name");
             if (file_exists($tempFullPath))
             {
                if (mkdir(JPATH_SITE.$destinationFolder,0755,true)) {
                if (copy($source = $tempFullPath, $dest = JPATH_SITE.$destinationFolder."/".$name)) {
                    return $destinationFolder."/".$name;
                } else
                {
                    error_log('could not copy '. "$source to $dest");

                }
                } else {
                    error_log('could not create folder '. JPATH_SITE.$destinationFolder);
                }
                return "";
             } else {
                error_log('FILE NOT FOUND: '. $tempFullPath);
             }
```

error_log is used to dump info to the server error log, you may remove it and replace it with the appropriate exceptions.

Comment: In order words what @Riccardo Zorn explained above, `type="file"` just generates the HTML but the PHP part (uploading the file) needs to be made by you. There are a lot of methods in the Joomla API when dealing with files. Check JFile for a start.

Answer (score 1):

There is nice way of doing this in Joomla and this is code snippet from Joomla Documentation

Supposing this is the sample form

```
/*Sample Form either form form.xml file or from view file */
<form name="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file_upload" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>


/*File handling code over here*/
    <?php
/*
* File upload example
*/
//Retrieve file details from uploaded file, sent from upload form
$file = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('file_upload');

//Import filesystem libraries. Perhaps not necessary, but does not hurt
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

//Clean up filename to get rid of strange characters like spaces etc
$filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);

//Set up the source and destination of the file
$src = $file['tmp_name'];
$dest = JPATH_COMPONENT . DS . "uploads" . DS . $filename;

//First check if the file has the right extension, we need jpg only
if (strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename)) == 'jpg') 
{
   // TODO: Add security checks

   if (JFile::upload($src, $dest))
   {
      //Redirect to a page of your choice
   } 
   else
   {
      //Redirect and throw an error message
   }
}
else
{
   //Redirect and notify user file is not right extension
}
?>
```

More can be found on this link [How to use the filesystem package](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package)